# Return a JSON Object Array from class

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile-application

I have recently started trying to teach my self how to write Android applications and I am having a little difficulty understanding/implementing a method for passing an array of results from a class I am calling.

Since I am not sure how to perfectly layout this example, please bear with me!

I have my `MainActivity` which is calling the class `AsyncTaskParseJson` (which is partially Frankensteined from online examples). As it sits now, my MainActivity can call the class, and get back a string which displays true/false. I am hoping to return either an array, or an array converted into a string back to my MainActivity for further processing.

Code:

```
package jesse.jones.test;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Shadow on 9/16/14.
 */

// you can make this class as another java file so it will be separated from your main activity.
public class AsyncTaskParseJson extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    final String TAG = "AsyncTaskParseJson.java";
    String userEmail;
    String userPassword;
    String doAction;
    String reportArray;

    // set your json string url here
    String yourJsonStringUrl = <-url removed->;

    // contacts JSONArray
    JSONArray dataJsonArr = null;

    MainActivity mActivity;

    public AsyncTaskParseJson(MainActivity activity){
        mActivity = activity;


    }

    public void setCredentials(String inUserEmail,String inUserPassword){
        userEmail = inUserEmail;
        userPassword= inUserPassword;
    }

    public void setAction(String actionToTake){
        doAction = actionToTake;
    }

    protected String urlBuilderv1(String actionToTake,String inUserEmail, String inUserPassword){
        String urlString = <-url removed->

        if (actionToTake == "test"){
            urlString = <-url removed->
        }
        if (actionToTake == "login"){
            urlString = <-url removed->
        }

        if (actionToTake == "getReports"){
            urlString = <-url removed->
        }

        return urlString;
    }

    public String getReportArray(){

        return reportArray;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        String jsonReturnedResult = "NORETURN";
        String jsonReturnedMessage = null;
        String jsonReturnedReports = null;
        String result = null;

        try {

            // instantiate our json parser
            JasonParser jParser = new JasonParser();

            yourJsonStringUrl = urlBuilderv1(doAction,userEmail,userPassword);

            // get json string from url
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(yourJsonStringUrl);


            jsonReturnedResult = json.get("result").toString();
            //^^ I would like to take this JSONArray back to main activity
            //^^ instead of pulling a single string from it.
            result = jsonReturnedResult;


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String strFromDoInBg) {

        mActivity.onGetResults(strFromDoInBg);


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the get() method on your task reference after you call its execute() method. This will basically turn it into a synchronous task, but it will get you the String result. The type that your AsyncTask returns is that last "String" you have specified in "extends AsyncTask". Change that to whatever type you want to return.

Comment: So to clarify, by changing the last "String" to "ArrayList" I would be able to return an array? :P I can return a single string no problem. But that just a fraction of the complete data I need.

Comment: The last String is just the return type. You could use String [] to return an array of Strings from your doInBackground method.

Comment: I ended up programming an interface for returns, with this I can return as many strings, ints, arrays as I need. Being new to this android gig I didn't realize that its easier to find help with "java" than "android". I appreciate your input!